# Mysqli exception in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Trying to set up a project in Codeigniter I am having:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'missing: mysqli_real_escape_string or bad connection ID' in
>   /var/www/public/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:341\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/public/system/database/DB_driver.php(742):
>   CI_DB_mysqli_driver->escape_str('192.168.33.1')\n#1
>   /var/www/public/system/database/DB_active_rec.php(427):
>   CI_DB_driver->escape('192.168.33.1')\n#2
>   /var/www/public/system/database/DB_active_rec.php(366):
>   CI_DB_active_record->_where('addr', '192.168.33.1', 'AND ', true)\n#3
>   /var/www/public/application/classes/model.php(451):
>   CI_DB_active_record->where('addr', '192.168.33.1')\n#4
>   /var/www/public/application/classes/model.php(495):
>   Model::find_id('192.168.33.1', '*')\n#5
>   /var/www/public/application/classes/model.php(480):
>   Model::find_sub('192.168.33.1', NULL)\n#6
>   /var/www/public/application/core/CIL_Controller.php(981):
>   Model::find('192.168.33.1')\n#7
>   /var/www/public/application/core/CIL_Controller.php(104):
>   CIL_Controller->check_blocked()\n#8
>   /var/www/public/system/core/Controller in
>   /var/www/public/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on
>   line 341

I cannot figure out why

The part of the code that generate the error is:

```
if (function_exists('mysqli_real_escape_string') AND is_object($this->conn_id))
{
    $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception('missing: mysqli_real_escape_string or bad connection ID');
}
```

Comment: People still escaping strings in 2018. Why not using something much more secured like http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php ?

Comment: If you're using Codeigniter why not taking advantage of it, save some lines of code and let it handle that on its own?

Comment: Based on the stack trace it seems you are using a really old and obsolete version of CodeIgniter. You should consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

> Caution Security: the default character set The character set must be
>   set either at the server level, or with the API function
>   mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect mysqli_real_escape_string(). See
>   the concepts section on character sets for more information.

Or check if there are any errors when trying to connect

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
```

And if all ok do this

```
$str= $mysqli->real_escape_string($str)
```

Comment: In CodeIgniter the value of `$this->conn_id` is same thing as is returned by `new mysqli(...`